# Returning more than one image from a .NET web service

Tags: .net, web-services, arrays

I'm able to return an image as byte array from my .NET web service..

My question is this, what if i want to return more than a single image in one request.
For example, my web method currently looks something like this:

```
public byte[] GetImage(string filename)
```

BUT what I'm trying to work out is how i would achieve something more like this:

```
public ..?... GetAllMemberStuffInOneHit(string memberID)
```

This would return, for example, a few images, along with some other information such as a members name and department.

Can this be done? Please help, Thank you.

Comment: What kind of web service? WCF or ASMX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  Instead of returning just a byte array, create a DTO class that has the byte array as well as potentially other useful information (file name, content type, etc.).  Then just return an IList of those.  Something like this:

```
public class MyImage
{
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyImage()
    {
        // maybe initialize defaults here, etc.
    }
}

public List<MyImage> GetAllMemberStuffInOneHit(string memberID)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Since your method name implies that you want to return even more information, you could create more DTO classes and build them together to create a "member" object.  Something like this:

```
public class Member
{
    public List<MyImage> Images { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    // etc.
}

public Member GetAllMemberStuffInOneHit(string memberID)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ill let you know how it goes :)

Comment: You guys are brilliant! Thanks, it worked.
One final thing, in my client app, i had to change config values -BufferSize and MaxArrayLength etc... I changed them from 16384 and 65536 to 116384 and 165536 respectively. 
Why are these initially so restrictive, are there any risks in increasing these items?

Comment: @Mikey: The only risk, really, is allowing large data packets to be transferred across the service boundary.  At my last job we had it set at 2 GB, which was a little unsettling but worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to just return a `List<byte[]>` collection, like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<byte[]> GetAllImages(string memberID)
{
    List<byte[]> collection = new List<byte[]>();
    // fetch images one at a time and add to collection
    return collection;
}
```

To use this, you'll need this line at the top of your `Service.cs` file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```